# WSO2 as RPC server with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2

I have a following task:
WSO2 listening a RabbitMQ (amqp) queue for incoming message, call some DB procedure and reply back to specified in incoming message queue (reply_to property)  with specified Correlation Id (correlation_id property). 
I used dynamic message routing with Default endpoint (named RabbitMQ_DefEP) and CorrelationId
I spend some time to gathering information to make this work. Here is working example
It may be useful for others

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="RabbitMQRPCTest01" startOnLoad="true" transports="rabbitmq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log description="" level="custom">
                <property name="*****Rabbit MQ Start" value="********************************* headers"/>
            </log>
            <log level="headers"/>
            <log description="" level="custom">
                <property name="*****Rabbit MQ" value="********************************* full"/>
            </log>
            <log level="full"/>
            <log description="CorrId" level="custom">
                <property expression="$header" name="***Header="/>
                <property expression="$body" name="***Body="/>
            </log>
            <property description="Get Correlation Id" expression="get-property('transport', 'rabbitmq.message.correlation.id')" name="corrid" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="Get Reply To" expression="get-property('transport', 'RABBITMQ_REPLY_TO')" name="replto" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('corrid')" name="***CORRELATION ID="/>
                <property expression="get-property('replto')" name="***REPLY_TO="/>
            </log>
            <payloadFactory description="Set payload for procedure call" media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <p:CallPing xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                        <p:req>$1</p:req>
                    </p:CallPing>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body//ns:text" xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property description="HTTP_METHOD" name="HTTP_METHOD POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="POST"/>
            <property description="SOAPAction" name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" type="STRING" value=""/>
            <property description="messageType" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$body" name="*****Procedure params"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="DMSB_CFTEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log description="" level="custom">
                <property name="*****Rabbit MQ Reply started" value="*********************************"/>
            </log>
            <log description="Full Log" level="full"/>
            <header description="Build URI for AMQP" expression="fn:concat('rabbitmq:/AMQPProducerSample?rabbitmq.server.host.name=rabbitmq.ru&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=monitor&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=12345&amp;rabbitmq.connection.factory=RabbitMQConnectionFactory&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=', get-property('replto'))" name="To" scope="default"/>
            <log description="" level="custom">
                <property name="*****Rabbit MQ Reply END" value="*********************************"/>
            </log>
            <property description="Set Correlation Id" expression="get-property('corrid')" name="rabbitmq.message.correlation.id" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="RabbitMQ_DefEP"/>
            </call>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$body" name="****FAULT***************"/>
            </log>
            <log description="Log Props" level="full">
                <property name="text" value="An unexpected error occured. Executing fault sequence"/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" name="ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')" name="detail"/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')" name="exception"/>
                <property expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" name="ERROR_CODE"/>
            </log>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">esb</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
</proxy>
```